# wso2 api manager throws exception Error in invoking validate key via thrift

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I see this intermittent exception in my log file on unix server. My wso2 api manager is a standalone installation of 1.10.0. please help me understand this exception.

Stack trace below:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-16 08:19:40,350]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Message dispat
ched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = / {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-16 08:21:29,962]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Message dispat
ched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = / {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-16 08:33:48,425]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl} -
 Invalid session id for thrift authenticator. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-16 08:33:48,425] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl} -  Error in invoking validate key via thrift.. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-16 08:33:48,426]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftKeyValidatorClientPool} -  Login failed.. Authenticating again.. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftKeyValidatorClientPool}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-16 08:33:48,437]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2017-11-16 08:33:48,437-0500] from IP address  {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-11-16 08:33:48,476]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.EventPublisher} -  Session timed out for TCP,localhost:7614,TCP,localhost:7714,Thrift Session Expired Exception  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.EventPublisher}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your above logs, I can see following error log related to thrift

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-16 08:33:48,425] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl} -  Error in invoking validate key via thrift.. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl}
```

I don't really see a reason for above, but Can you please change to WSClient from ThriftClient. This configuration resides on api-manager.xml file.

There could be a connection issue related to thrift in your node.

Comment: Changing it to WSClient worked. However, I need to monitor for few more days and see. I still don't understand why the thrift didn't work, although I have a one node configuration. I recently changed the admin password, do you think that might have impacted the thrift client authentication...because I saw those errors in one of the log files?
I found this blog helpful as well:
http://engwar.com/post/139449855402/wso2-api-manager-switching-to-wsclient-for-key